# Two Factor Authentication Proper Implementation (Possible bug found?)

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I was writing a web scraper for a previous employer and it required me to login and it also did a two factor authentication if I had never logged in with that user before.

Well... what I came to find out was that after passing the token, along with username and password, **It would never ask me for two factor authentication on my web scraper, but it would in the browser.** I have even done this with a test username/password of someone who has never logged in.

1. Is it that easy to get by two-factor authentication?
2. Without divulging the code (for security reasons), what are possible reasons that this could happen?
3. Any ways to make this more secure? Could it just be running java script validation on the two factor, and since my web scraper doesn't have java script it never hits it?
4. What is the most proper/secure implementation of a two factor code requirement?

Comment: if you never logged in what that user, or user agent? Token being a cookie?

Comment: I log in with an authorized issuer, but I am also passing a csrf token for validation. The cookie is saved for the session, but it does not save across instances of my program.